# Re-using own sonata blocks

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i am new to sonata block's, and i stumbled on to this, i am not sure i understand it correctly, i know i can set default values for blocks, and i know i can generate blocks with specific settings in twig via:

```
{{ sonata_block_render({ 'type': 'sonata.block.service.rss' }, {
    'title': 'Sonata Project\'s Feeds',
    'url': 'https://sonata-project.org/blog/archive.rss'
}) }}
```

But when i just insert the block's into the sonata admin backend, i cannot set the settings here, do i really have to make a block that just has a template whose only purpose is to render another block with settings?

I know this is confusing, here is what my config looks like:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        affiliate.block.statistics:
```

Here is what id like to be able to do:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        affiliate.block.statistics:
            settings:
                title: potato
```

I can do this, but "title" is not overwriting the default title?

Or is this done under the sonata_admin root?

Cant do this either:

```
sonata_admin:
   dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { position: right, type: affiliate.block.statistics, title: 'title' }
```

This is how i set the defaults in my block service

```
public function setDefaultSettings(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'url'            => false,
        'title'          => '123',
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config.yml you should have a block to define the sonata_admin

```
sonata_admin:
    title:      My Admin       
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                type:  affiliate.block.statistics:
                settings:
                    title: potato

            # You can define multiple blocks. 
            # e.g. a Standard Sonata Statistics Block.

            -
                class:    col-md-3 col-xs-6  
                position: top  # zone in the dashboard
                type:     sonata.admin.block.stats   # block id
                settings:
                    code:  app.admin.news_comments   # admin code - service id
                    icon:  fa fa-magic               # font awesome icon
                    text:  Approved Comments
                    color: bg-aqua                   # colors: bg-green, bg-red etc.
                    filters:                         # search filter values
                        approved: { value: true }
```

Then in your existing sonata_block: part of your config.yml (or sonata.yml) config you simply list the block to "enable" it.

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        affiliate.block.statistics
```